# Create a multifuctional Javascript reveal function that works without duplicating the code

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax

This is my first post on stackflow. I am pretty new to programming but **I am trying to figure out how to efficiently produce a multi-functional function that will allow me to reveal information one step at a time for multiple divs/blocks seperately.** For instance, this function only work for this specific button and div.

```
<!-- Function 1 -->
  (function () {
    var n = 1;
    window.ShowStep1 = function () {
      document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + n++).style.visibility = "visible";
      if (!document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + n)) {
        document.getElementById("step1").disabled = true;
      }
      document.getElementById("reset1").disabled = false;
    }
    window.ResetSteps1 = function () {
      document.getElementById("step1").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("reset1").disabled = true;
      var i = 1, step1; n = 1;
      while (step1 = document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + i)) {
        step1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        i++
      }
    }
  })();
```

Where it will only work for the following:

```
<p>
 <input type="button" onclick="ShowStep1()" value="Steps" id="step1"/> 
 <input type="button" onclick="ResetSteps1()" value="Reset" id="reset1" disabled="true"/>
</p>
```

**But I want to do this with for many buttons with unique id's without having to manually make new functions.** As of right now, in order for me to make multiple functions I have to manually create several of the **Function 1** sets of code. How can I do this more efficiently if say I wanted to do 10 of these? The code works fine but I dont want to repeat myself. This code comes from the following link:
[MathJax-demos-web-link](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web/blob/master/reveal-steps.html)

But I modified it in my own way. Any help and tips would be appreciated! Thanks in advance. **For some reason there is an error in snippet but if you run it on jsfiddle it works fine.** This is the entire script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax v3 dynamic equations using CSS and javascript</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]},
    chtml: {
      displayAlign: 'left'
    },
    startup: {
      pageReady: function () {
        //
        //  Do the usual startup (which does a typeset).
        //  When that is all done, un-hide the page.
        //
        return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(function () {
          document.getElementById("hidden").disabled = true;
        });
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Function 1 -->
  (function () {
    var n = 1;
    window.ShowStep1 = function () {
      document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + n++).style.visibility = "visible";
      if (!document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + n)) {
        document.getElementById("step1").disabled = true;
      }
      document.getElementById("reset1").disabled = false;
    }
    window.ResetSteps1 = function () {
      document.getElementById("step1").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("reset1").disabled = true;
      var i = 1, step1; n = 1;
      while (step1 = document.getElementById("Step1" + "-" + i)) {
        step1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        i++
      }
    }
  })();
  
<!-- Function 2 -->
  (function () {
    var n = 1;
    window.ShowStep2 = function () {
      document.getElementById("Step2" + "-" + n++).style.visibility = "visible";
      if (!document.getElementById("Step2" + "-" + n)) {
        document.getElementById("step2").disabled = true;
      }
      document.getElementById("reset2").disabled = false;
    }
    window.ResetSteps2 = function () {
      document.getElementById("step2").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("reset2").disabled = true;
      var i = 1, step2; n = 1;
      while (step2 = document.getElementById("Step2" + "-" + i)) {
        step2.style.visibility = "hidden";
        i++
      }
    }
  })();
  
  </script>

  <style>
    #Step1-1, #Step1-2, #Step1-3, #Step1-4, #Step1-5,
    #Step2-1, #Step2-2, #Step2-3, #Step2-4, #Step2-5 {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Dynamic Equations in MathJax</h1>

<div id="frame">
<p>
Expand the following:
\begin{align}
  (x+1)^2
    &= \cssId{Step1-1}{(x+1)(x+1)}            \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-2}{{} = x(x+1) + 1(x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-3}{{} = (x^2+x) + (x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-4}{{} = x^2 + (x + x) + 1}  \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-5}{{} = x^2 + 2x + 1}
\end{align}
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" onclick="ShowStep1()" value="Steps" id="step1"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="ResetSteps1()" value="Reset" id="reset1" disabled="true"/>
</p>

</div>

<div id="frame">
<p>
Expand the following:
\begin{align}
  (x+1)^2
    &= \cssId{Step2-1}{(x+1)(x+1)}            \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-2}{{} = x(x+1) + 1(x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-3}{{} = (x^2+x) + (x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-4}{{} = x^2 + (x + x) + 1}  \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-5}{{} = x^2 + 2x + 1}
\end{align}
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" onclick="ShowStep2()" value="Steps" id="step2"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="ResetSteps2()" value="Reset" id="reset2" disabled="true"/>
</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main change will be to create one version each of the two functions which take parameters rather than storing step information in variables which happens now.

However, before that, a couple of other observations:

- The HTML is not 'legal' - ids need to be unique and frame ids are not unique in the given code.
- This extra CSS styling a slight alarm bell, does it mean you can't have more than 5 steps?

  ```
   #Step1-1, #Step1-2, #Step1-3, #Step1-4, #Step1-5,
   #Step2-1, #Step2-2, #Step2-3, #Step2-4, #Step2-5 {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
  ```

This snippet renames the frame ids so they are unique, removes the multi-style settings above and substitutes the more general 'style elements whose id starts with Step'.

It then makes just one step-revealing function and one reset function and calls them with parameters. It does not try to store values of 'n' to show where the revealing has got to in each case but instead works it out each time by looking for those steps that are already visible.

Note that (as noted in the question) it is not possible to run this in the SO snippet system which is sandboxed so here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax v3 dynamic equations using CSS and javascript</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]},
    chtml: {
      displayAlign: 'left'
    },
    startup: {
      pageReady: function () {
        //
        //  Do the usual startup (which does a typeset).
        //  When that is all done, un-hide the page.
        //
        return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(function () {
          document.getElementById("hidden").disabled = true;
        });
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

  <script>

  (function () {
    window.ShowStep = function (el, id) {
      //go through all the elements with id id-n and set the first non visible one to visible
      const steps = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="' + id + '"]');
      for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
         if (steps[i].style.visibility != 'visible') {
           steps[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
           break;
         }
       }
      el.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    }
    window.ResetSteps = function (el, id, reset) {
      el.disabled = false;
      //go through all the elements with id id-n and set them all to hidden
      const steps = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="' + id + '"]');
      for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
           steps[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
         }      
    } 
  })();
    </script>
<style>
[id^="Step"] {
  visibility : hidden;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Dynamic Equations in MathJax</h1>

<div id="frame1">
<p>
Expand the following:
\begin{align}
  (x+1)^2
    &= \cssId{Step1-1}{(x+1)(x+1)}            \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-2}{{} = x(x+1) + 1(x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-3}{{} = (x^2+x) + (x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-4}{{} = x^2 + (x + x) + 1}  \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step1-5}{{} = x^2 + 2x + 1}
\end{align}
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" onclick="ShowStep(this, 'Step1', 'reset1');" value="Steps"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="ResetSteps(this, 'Step1', 'reset1')" value="Reset" disabled="true"/>
</p>

</div>

<div id="frame2">
<p>
Expand the following:
\begin{align}
  (x+1)^2
    &= \cssId{Step2-1}{(x+1)(x+1)}            \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-2}{{} = x(x+1) + 1(x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-3}{{} = (x^2+x) + (x+1)}    \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-4}{{} = x^2 + (x + x) + 1}  \\[3px]
    &\cssId{Step2-5}{{} = x^2 + 2x + 1}
\end{align}
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" onclick="ShowStep(this, 'Step2', 'reset2');" value="Steps" id="step2"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="ResetSteps(this, 'Step2', 'reset2')" value="Reset" id="reset2" disabled="true"/>
</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the great help A Haworth! This approach is new to me. I am sure I have seen various variations of this technique around before but never really understood it. Also, I do see what you mean by the HTML not being legal and for the CSS, I believe that was my manual way of figuring creating a solution. It seems so simple how you did it. I see the logic but I still need more practice and build my fundamentals. Are there any learning source or books you recommend for js within this level? Currently I am reading Eloquent Javascript by Haverbeke and The Road to React by Wieruch.

Comment: Also, with your code above. I noticed that the unique id -1, -2,... -n of Step1 and Step 2 from "\cssId{Step1-1}{...} & \cssId{Step1-1}{...}" does not matter. It can have any unique value and it will still reveal them in the same order. Where does that logic come from in the script and why is able to do that. I dont think it will change how I use it but I am just curious because of I want to have a better understanding of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Those ids are created by the math typesetting package. The code in this answer doesn’t need to use them as it’s easier to find the children at run time, saves having to store a special n for each child, the need for this was basically why the code in the question had a copy of the function for each example.

Comment: I see. Okay, I will look into that and thank you!

Comment: @Haworth How could I hide all of the cssid's from the beginning so that it starts hidden?

Comment: Hi, what is it that you want to start hidden? The individual steps start hidden, what other stuff needs to be hidden?

Comment: Yes, the individual steps.. it is mainly a preferences thing. But also because it helps with the Reset button at the start becasuse it is disabled at the beginning and I have to reset the "Steps" button for me to Reset.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to be hidden. And I also don't grasp what the problem with the reset buttons is - they are disabled at the start (not that it really matters to the user I suspect as hitting it if there are no steps showing just does nothing anyway) and a button gets enabled if there are any of its steps showing.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for being patient... There are 2 things. 1) The math steps are revealed at the beginning when the page is loaded or refreshed. I would like to have the steps hidden at the beginning when loading or refreshing of the page. And 2) when the page is loaded or refreshed, the "Reset" button is disabled and I have to press the "Step" button first so I can enable the "Reset" button and hide the steps...

Comment: Desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/jambriz2/4xneyskw/  Current output: https://jsfiddle.net/jambriz2/vhtfdg5n/4/

Comment: Sorry, a piece of CSS which I talked about in the text but failed to add to the actual code was missing. This sets the steps to visibility hidden at the start.

Comment: I see. So it would have to be set outside of the function in that case, right? For it to work? Thanks.